# What does that line of TypeScript mean?

Tags: typescript

I just found a line in a TypeScript file inside a class which looks like

```
private handlers: ((event: string) => void)[]
```

Then there is another function:

```
  private fire(event: string): void {
    for (const handler of this.handlers) {
      handler(event);
    }
  }
```

So my guess would be that each array element has a function which can be called but I really don't understand how this is working. If every element has that function attached which returns always void, shouldn't be all array elements complete empty?

Or is this some magical TypeScript syntax?

Comment: It's defining an array _of functions_.

Comment: "*my guess would be that each array element has a function which can be called but I really don't understand how this is working*" It's not magic. It's just basic TS: `(event: string) => void` is type notation for a function. `X[]` is type notation for an array of `X`es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets `[]` in typescript declares an array. And the syntax of `(...params: any[]) => any` declares a function. So combined together (and using the parentheses!) you will get an array of functions.

This means that the `handlers` property is an array of functions, which all take one parameter `event` of type `string` and return `void`. So the elements inside the array don't all "*have*" a function, that can be called, but they *are* functions.

The important thing to note here, is that the array only holds the functions. They are not invoked. To actually run the functions you'd have to obtain them (through iteration or indexing the array) and invoke them, with the specified parameter(s), like you would every other function.

Comment: Okay thanks i got that part, but shouldn't the element be empty with void return type? I think an array which is writeable but not readable makes no sens, what am i missing?

Comment: What do you mean by elements that should be empty, and why is the array not readable...it's read in the `fire` function

Comment: For me that first line looks sth like Array.fill( () => undefined)

Comment: No...it's like Array.map(() => () => { })), because the array is not filled with `undefined`, but with functions

Comment: sry.. I really try to understand that but the definition of these functions in the array already say that the return type is void? For example if im calling the fire function in the example in the posting. Im calling every function in the array with a string param and.. damn i just found the the function which is added and now it all makes sense. Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's easier to understand it you read it like this:

```
private handlers: Function[]
```

Comment: yes, that way i can understand it. Im just really confused about the return type void

Comment: Void only specifies, that the functions inside the array will return nothing when invoked...it's just like every other function in TS/JS

Comment: @MrCodingB Plenty of functions do not return `void` in JS/TS. Simple examples: `parseInt`, `Boolean`, `() => 4`, and many, many, *many* more.

Comment: Yeah sorry..."every" other function, was a bit wrong...I just meant that it's nothing special or uncommon for this to be the case